# How to type faster on vscode?

Tags: linux, performance, visual-studio-code, lag

I don't know if it's actually a problem on other computers, but in my case, when I type on vscode, it feels like that there is a delay between my keyboard stroke and the letter displayed on the screen. Compared to that of dartpad.darlang.org website, it feels sluggish. Even when I'm typing this question, on this website, it feels very snappy. How do I reduce this input lag on vscode, or simply just make it faster? I've disabled all the extensions, even the built-in ones as much as I can. The only extension in my vscode right now are the flutter and dart extension for my devlopment. Thanks for helping :)

Btw, im on manjaro linux

Comment: VS Code uses Electron, which is based on Chromium - which depends on your computer's accelerated graphics capabilities. Are you running the latest reputable graphics drivers for your computer's graphics chipset?

Comment: In this thread, the OP says it turned out to be other software running on their computer (granted, running Windows, not Linux) that was chewing-up their GPU which slowed down VS Code: https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/c9gt0e/typing_lag_in_vs_code/

Comment: why not test with all extensions disabled?

Comment: I can confirm this issue exists. There is a tiny bit of input lag, which is really annoying, and causes me to make mistakes while typing.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem once and it was caused by an extension used to toggle insert mode.

Try to remove some addons.